# How do I get a Facebook access token in PHP while using oauth2 in JS?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-authentication, facebook-login

I am using FB connect and login button of facebook on a site.

I logged in using it and then on login, I reload the page, I tried to get the cookie having access_token in PHP but failed to do so. Following is my js code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'xxxxxxxx',
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        oauth      : true
      });

      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        window.location.reload();
      });
    };
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));
```

Fb login button code:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" scope="email,user_checkins" >Login with Facebook</div>
```

Now I when user login using facebook, I try to get its data using access_token, but not getting that access_token from cookies.
I am using following code:

```
$cookie = $this->get_facebook_cookie(APP_ID, APP_SECRET);



        echo $cookie['access_token'];
        if(isset($cookie['access_token'])){  

            $user = json_decode(@file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' .$cookie['access_token']));
            echo $user->id;
            if(isset($user->id)){
             //       my stuff

            }                    
        }
```

I doubt it is not even getting cookie. While it logged at client side. So how can I get data in PHP then? need to again repeat whole login process on PHP side too? How do I deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the Facebook php sdk which automatically loads the cookie set by the js sdk? https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

Comment: above is the fb connect scenario when user login and a popup opens so in that case, I was using JS.